# android BLE polar h7

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i would to to show the value of heart rate from Polar H7 on TextView in Fragment (not on the Activity). I used Google's example from the address: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html I have made BluetoothLeService class, and SampleGattAttributes help class. I'm posting the code of all three class. But, in the end my TextView does not change. Can you tell me where the break is. Thanks.

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.schleewoon.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.schleewoon.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.schleewoon.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.schleewoon.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.schleewoon.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";



public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


// Various callback methods defined by the BLE API.
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
        new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
            int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    // Result of a characteristic read operation
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
            int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

};


private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile. Data
    // parsing is carried out as per profile specifications.
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" +
                    stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}




@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
 * 
 * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) public boolean initialize() {
    // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter
    // through
    // BluetoothManager.
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
 * 
 * @param address
 *            The device address of the destination device.
 * 
 * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The
 *         connection result is reported asynchronously through the
 *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 *         callback.
 */

public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device. Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null
            && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the
    // autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The
 * disconnection result is reported asynchronously through the
 * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 * callback.
 */
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

/**
 * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure
 * resources are released properly.
 */
public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}

/**
 * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read
 * result is reported asynchronously through the
 * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
 * callback.
 * 
 * @param characteristic
 *            The characteristic to read from.
 */
public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

/**
 * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
 * 
 * @param characteristic
 *            Characteristic to act on.
 * @param enabled
 *            If true, enable notification. False otherwise.
 */

public void setCharacteristicNotification(
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    try {
        // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic
                    .getDescriptor(UUID
                            .fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor
                    .setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Exception while setting up notification for heartrate.", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This
 * should be invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()}
 * completes successfully.
 * 
 * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
 */
public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null)
        return null;

    return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
}

}
```

```
  public class SampleGattAttributes {

private static HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

static {
    // Sample Services.
    attributes.put("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Generic access");
    attributes.put("00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Generic attribute");
    attributes.put("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Immediate alert");
    attributes.put("00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Link loss");
    attributes.put("00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Tx Power");
    attributes.put("00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Current Time Service");


    attributes.put("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Heart Rate Service");
    attributes.put("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Device Information Service");
    // Sample Characteristics.
    attributes.put(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT, "Heart Rate Measurement");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");

    attributes.put("00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Device Name");
    attributes.put("00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Appearance");
    attributes.put("00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Peripheral Privacy Flag");
    attributes.put("00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Reconnection Address");
    attributes.put("00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    attributes.put("00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Service Changed");
    attributes.put("00002A06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Alert level");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");

}

public static String lookup(String uuid, String defaultName) {
    String name = attributes.get(uuid);
    return name == null ? defaultName : name;
}
```

```
public class CO2Fragment extends Fragment  {


private TextView totalTimeTitle;





private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
private final static String TAG = CO2Fragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int BIND_AUTO_CREATE = 0x0001;
private String mDeviceAddress;
private boolean mConnected = false;




// Code to manage Service lifecycle.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName,
            IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service)
                .getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up
        // initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

// Handles various events fired by the Service.
// ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED: connected to a GATT server.
// ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED: disconnected from a GATT server.
// ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED: discovered GATT services.
// ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE: received data from the device. This can be a
// result of read
// or notification operations.
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED
                .equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED
                .equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the
            // user interface.
            //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            // mButtonStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent
                    .getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};



private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter
            .addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ...

    totalTimeTitle = (TextView) co2view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCO2TotalTimeTitle);



    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothLeService.class);
    // TODO: Lars added this
    getActivity().startService(gattServiceIntent);
    getActivity().bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());

    ...

    return co2view;
}

private void displayData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            totalTimeTitle.setText("TOTAL TIME + CURRENT PULSE: " + data);


        }
        else{

            totalTimeTitle.setText("TOTAL TIME ---" );

        }

}
```

Comment: Are you receiving the data from the sensor?

Comment: So you know you're getting inside here `} else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                displayData(intent
                        .getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
            }` ? If so, maybe put a toast there so you can see what you are getting? That way you at least know all of that is working.

Comment: Well, tbh i'm not sure. I tried my polar h7 with some other simple apps, and its working ok, so i made code to open ble with my app, and here i got stuck.  Good idea, i'll try it now with toast

Comment: Okay, so we know the sensor works. I think you need to confirm that your app is receiving the data from the sensor. Toasts are handy to use as a debug output to your app. You can do something like this: `String sensorData =  intent .getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA); Toast.makeText(this,"Sensor sent "+ sensorData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`.

Comment: Sensor sent null       :(

Comment: :/ Sorry... I'd say use toast or whatever debugging method to follow through the code starting with connecting to the sensor, and see if the characteristic notification setup is working.

Comment: Does this block throw the exception: `try {
        // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {...` ?

Comment: Hm, i tried with toast there. this method is never call :/

Comment: DigitalNinja, any chance for private message? i'm still stuck with BLE polar hrm, but i think i/m almost done, i can see polar in app.. need some more help :/

Comment: I can try and help you. What are you stuck on?

Comment: ok, i'll try in short terms: I'm using https://github.com/mobilars/BLEConnect in my app. BLEConnect app working perfect on my LG, and I'm trying to implement that code in my app. All is good till last step - i can see Polar H7 on my Dialog (so my app see Polar). But when i click on Polar on list and want to show pulse on TextView on Activity, my app crashing.. on method:   mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, true);if you can ping me on email: malbasicd@gmail.com or Skype: schleewon, i can give you complete view :) Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll email you.

Comment: I can see all polar data: name, address, etc.. it is just some click/method problem i believe

Comment: Ok, thank you, waiting for the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
    int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
```

in the sample code is expected to return the bit mask for the supported characteristic fields. **It doesn't.** It returns the characteristic properties, like PROPERTY_NOTIFY.

To get the bit mask for the supported characteristic fields, in the case of the example's Heart Rate Measurement characteristic, the first value of the characteristic needs to be read and used.

Thus replacing the line

```
int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
```

with something like

```
byte[] charValue = characteristic.getValue();
byte flag = charValue[0];
```

will work correctly.